# jQuery checkbox auto disable and re-enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, checkbox

I have my HTML code and my JavaScript code like this (I'm using jQuery)

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="program" id="box-1" /> Desktop Programming
<select name="lang-1" id="select-1" disabled>
    <option value="c">C/C++</option>
    <option value="vb">VB</option>
    <option value="cs">C#</option>
</select><br /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="web" id="box-2" /> Web Development
<select name="lang-2" id="select-2" disabled>
    <option value="asp">ASP</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="ror">Ruby on Rails</option>
</select><br /><br />
```

JavaScript (jQuery) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x;
    $("#box-" + x).click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            $("#select-" + x).prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $("#select-" + x).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

And I want when I checked the programming checkbox, the programming select option (beside the checkbox) is enable. As well as when I checked the web dev checkbox, the web dev select option is enable. But my code doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your `x` variable is undefined you havent set a value for it

Comment: How to define it? Meanwhile i have many `#box` and `#select`, not just 2 ID

Comment: To define a variable use **var**

Comment: I used already but I'm not define it yet, `var x;`

Comment: There are several errors. As Patrick pointed out, your x is undefined. x needs to be the number of the checkbox. Also, I think `$this` doesn't work. It should be `$(this)`. See my working solution below!

Comment: working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5omaqgkq/1/

Comment: Thanks Nem ! You're great

Comment: hi @LSNRabbani below are also some great people apart for me who did great stuff too So appreciate  them to man...

Comment: Hi too Amin ! Ya I know that alot people help me to resolved this error, i'm sorry for that, but big thanks too to all of your answers sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using classes in stead of ID's with a random number. 
I would give all my checkboxes the class "box" and the id 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Also, I think `$this` doesn't work. It has to be `$(this)`.

Then your code would look like (working example):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').click(function(){
        var x= $(this).attr("id");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#select-" + x).prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $("#select-" + x).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="program" class="box" id="1" /> Desktop Programming
<select name="lang-1" id="select-1" disabled>
    <option value="c">C/C++</option>
    <option value="vb">VB</option>
    <option value="cs">C#</option>
</select><br /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="web" class="box" id="2" /> Web Development
<select name="lang-2" id="select-2" disabled>
    <option value="asp">ASP</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="ror">Ruby on Rails</option>
</select><br /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

For things like this use classes , no need for ID.

Right now your variable `x` is undefined and without a loop to parse the ID's it won't work

```
<input type="checkbox" class="box" /> Desktop Programming
<select name="lang-1" class="select" disabled>
```

JS

```
$('input:checkbox.box').change(function(){
   $(this).next('.select').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

If the layout is such that the select is not right after the input we can modify traverse a bit

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/q6oy0en8/)

Please have one same class to all of your checkbox here i taken as `checkbox` then your HTML will look like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="program" class="checkbox" id="box-1" /> Desktop Programming
<select name="lang-1" id="select-1" disabled>
    <option value="c">C/C++</option>
    <option value="vb">VB</option>
    <option value="cs">C#</option>
 </select><br /><br />

 <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="web" class="checkbox" id="box-2" /> Web Development
  <select name="lang-2" id="select-2" disabled>
     <option value="asp">ASP</option>
     <option value="php">PHP</option>
     <option value="ror">Ruby on Rails</option>
  </select><br /><br />
```

add  write this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
      var checked_id = $(this).prop('id');
      var a = checked_id.slice(4);

      $("#select-"+a).prop('disabled',!this.checked);
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are lots of answers here, much of which are better ways to do what you are trying with smaller cleaner code. But for the sake of it I am adding this answer to show you what was wrong with code you wrote and a working example.

So you declared variable `x` but never assigned it a value. It seems like you wanted to loop over the checkboxes and use the index `x` to assign the event. Since you started using IDs with 1 we need to compensate in the code for it. Then since `x` has no scope to our event directly we need to find the value of `x` since when the event runs it will only have the last value of `x`.

All HTML I left the same and only altered the javascript. As I said there are much better ways to do this and there are many answers here that show it but this is to show you what you were doing wrong.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/quyn4y23/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Find all checkboxes and get the length of all found
    var x, inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]'), length = inputs.length;
    // For each checkbox assign event
    for (x = 1; x <= length; x++) {
        $("#box-" + x).click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            // Find the number in the checkbox id
            var x = $this.attr('id').replace("box-", "");
            // Use number to find correct select
            if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                $("#select-" + x).prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $("#select-" + x).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```